# NSOutLineView with nested NSArray

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have nested n level dynamic array, i want to bind it with `NSOutlineView`,
 but i not getting how to bind it with `NSOutlineView` using its four delegate methods.

Nested Array like :

```
(
 {
    id = 3;
    summary = "req 1";
    "sub_requirement" =         
    (
        {
             id = 16;
            "sub_requirement" = "";
            summary = "sub req 1";
        }
    );

},
{ 
    id = 5;
    summary = "req 1-1";
    "sub_requirement" =       
    (
        {
            id = 17;
            "sub_requirement" = "";
            summary = "sub req 1-1";
        },
        {

            id = 21;
            "sub_requirement" = "";
            summary = "req 1";
        }
    );
},
    {
    id = 7;
    summary = "req 1 1";
    "sub_requirement" =         
    (            
        {
            approved = 1;
            budget = 3600;
            description = "";
            estimate = 3600;
            "fk_feature" = 4;
            "fk_parent" = 7;
            "fk_requirementtype" = 1;
            id = 18;
            "sub_requirement" = "";
            summary = "sub req 11";
        }
    );

},

{
    id = 8;
    "sub_requirement" = "";
    summary = "req 1 2";
},

{
    id = 12;
    "sub_requirement" = "";
    summary = "req 1";
},

{
    id = 14;
    "sub_requirement" = "";
    summary = req1;
}
)
```

Comment: Part of your problem is that the second level down is NSDictionaries.  Outline views don't play well with dictionaries because there is no ordering defined on their entries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [NSTreeController](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTreeController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), some links and tutorials available [here](http://headnix.com/blog/69/using-nstreecontroller-in-nsoutlineview).